# Unable to install mysql connector using PIP in python

Tags: python, pip, mysql-connector-python

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httpie (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for httpie
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1108)'))) - skipping

Python **version:3.8**
OS: Windows 8 64 bit

Comment: You can try to ignore SSL errors with `pip install --trusted-host pypi.org`

Comment: what was the pip command you actually tried?
`pip install mysql` ?

Comment: You are using python3.8 then you should install mysql8.0

Answer (score 2):

according to [mysql connector docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) the pip command is: `pip install mysql-connector-python`